# Update Textview from a Separate Placeholder Fragment using ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am developing a podcast app and I have two pages right now. A listening page and a list of podcasts page. I placed my MainActivity at the bottom of this question with my object and singleton classes.

So my problem is when I navigate from the second page (the list of podcasts) back to the first page (Now Playing) where there will be a media player added shortly.

The code to move from Page 2 to Page 1 is:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true); // now playing
```

but when I call something like this directly after the above statement:

```
home_title.setText(app.getCurrentPodcast().getTitle());
```

I get a NullPointerException.

I'm confused on how to update a TextView from another fragment within a PlaceHolder class which uses a standard ViewPager object. I want to be able to update the `home_title` from another fragment or thread but I don't know how. Help?

Podcast Object:

```
package Objects;

/**
 * XmlPodcastObject.java
 *
 * This object is designed to handle the XML content from the podcasts on the Prindle Site
 *
 * @author Alexander Miller, 2016
 */
public class XmlPodcastObject {

    private String title;
    private String podcastUrl;
    private String storyUrl;
    private String content;
    private String summary;
    private String timeOfStream;

    /**
     * XmlPodcastObject
     *
     * XmlPodcastObject contains all of the information for podcasts streamed on the app.
     * @param titl String title of the podcast
     * @param imageUr String image url of the podcast
     * @param storyUr String url for the story of the podcast
     * @param conten String all of the content explaining the podcast
     * @param summar String a breif summary of the content
     * @param timeOfStrea String duration of the podcast in HH:mm:ss
     */
    public XmlPodcastObject(String titl, String imageUr, String storyUr, String conten, String summar, String timeOfStrea)
    {
        this.title = titl;
        this.podcastUrl = imageUr;
        this.storyUrl = storyUr;
        this.content = conten;
        this.summary = summar;
        this.timeOfStream = timeOfStrea;
    }

    public XmlPodcastObject()
    {

    }

    //=========================================================================================
    // <Getters/Setters>
    //=========================================================================================
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPodcastUrl() {
        return podcastUrl;
    }

    public void setPodcastUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.podcastUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getStoryUrl() {
        return storyUrl;
    }

    public void setStoryUrl(String storyUrl) {
        this.storyUrl = storyUrl;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getTimeOfStream() {
        return timeOfStream;
    }

    public void setTimeOfStream(String timeOfStream) {
        this.timeOfStream = timeOfStream;
    }
    //=========================================================================================
    // </Getters/Setters>
    //=========================================================================================
}
```

Singleton:

```
package Utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Objects.XmlPodcastObject;

/**
 * Created by depauw on 12/3/15.
 */
public class App {

    private ArrayList<XmlPodcastObject> podcastArray;
    private XmlPodcastObject currentPodcast;

    private static App ourInstance = new App();

    public static App getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public App() {
    }

    public ArrayList<XmlPodcastObject> getPodcastArray() {
        return podcastArray;
    }

    public int getPodcastArraySize(){
        try{
            return podcastArray.size();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void setPodcastArray(ArrayList<XmlPodcastObject> podcastArray) {
        this.podcastArray = podcastArray;
    }

    public XmlPodcastObject getCurrentPodcast() {
        return currentPodcast;
    }

    public void setCurrentPodcast(XmlPodcastObject currentPodcast) {
        this.currentPodcast = currentPodcast;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package edu.depauw.prindle.examiningethics;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Objects.XmlPodcastObject;
import Utils.App;
import Utils.PodcastListArrayAdapter;
import Utils.XMLParser;

/*
 * - hambuger icon no swipe functionality.
 * - move settings to new activity, access via menu option
 * - add singleton class for cache
 * - once a day notification of new RSS feed object
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static boolean developerMode = false;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private static ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Microphone action coming soon.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.section_podcast_list);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.section_now_playing);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{

        private ListView Listv;
        private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
        private static App app;
        private TextView home_title;

        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        private PodcastListArrayAdapter podcastListArrayAdapter;

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
            app = new App();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = null;

            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1)
            {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

                home_title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_media_layout_track_title);

                try
                {
                    home_title.setText(app.getCurrentPodcast().getTitle());
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (app.getPodcastArraySize() == 0 && isNetworkAvailable())
                {
                    new AsyncTaskParseJson(false).execute();
                }
            }
            else {

                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_podcast_list, container, false);

                // UI binding
                swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
                swipeContainer.setColorSchemeColors(Color.rgb(253, 221, 100), Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
                Listv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_podcast_list_podcast_listview);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_podcast_list_section_label);

                // Setup refresh listener which triggers new data loading
                swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        // Your code to refresh the list here.
                        // Make sure you call swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false)
                        // once the network request has completed successfully.

                        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                            new AsyncTaskParseJson(true).execute();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet connection found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Onclick listener to return to the listening page.
                Listv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true); // now playing

                        app.setCurrentPodcast(app.getPodcastArray().get(position));
                    }
                });

                if (app.getPodcastArraySize() == 0 && isNetworkAvailable())
                {
                    new AsyncTaskParseJson(true).execute();
                }
                else if(app.getPodcastArraySize() != 0)
                {
                    podcastListArrayAdapter = new PodcastListArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_podcast_list_item, app.getPodcastArray());
                }
                else
                {
                    // error
                    Log.d(""+this.getClass().getName(),"Error 1");
                }

                textView.setText("Podcasts");
            }

            return rootView;
        }

        /**
         * isNetworkAvailable
         *
         * @return boolean true is internet is connected or connecting. False if off or none found.
         */
        private boolean isNetworkAvailable()
        {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        }


        /**
         * AsyncTaskParseJson
         *
         * This asynchronous task downloads all of the podcasts available and
         * returns a ListView compatible set of content.
         */
        public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
        {
            ArrayList<XmlPodcastObject> array = new ArrayList<>();
            private boolean setToArray;

            public AsyncTaskParseJson(boolean setToArray)
            {
                this.setToArray = setToArray;
            }

            // All static variables
            static final String URL = "http://examiningethics.org/feed/podcast/";

            // XML node keys
            static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
            static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
            static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
            static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
            static final String KEY_ENCLOSURE = "enclosure";
            static final String KEY_SUMMARY = "itunes:summary";
            static final String KEY_DURATION = "itunes:duration";

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){}

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
            {
                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                // looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    XmlPodcastObject obj = new XmlPodcastObject(parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE),
                            parser.getValue(e, KEY_ENCLOSURE), parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK),
                            parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC), parser.getValue(e, KEY_SUMMARY),
                            parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));

                    if(developerMode)
                    {
                        Log.d("PodcastActivity ONCLICK", "Title: " + obj.getTitle() + " " +
                                "Podcast Link: " + obj.getPodcastUrl() + " " +
                                "Story Link: " + obj.getStoryUrl() + " " +
                                "Duration: " + obj.getTimeOfStream() + " " +
                                "Content: " + obj.getContent() + " " +
                                "Summary: " + obj.getSummary());
                    }

                    array.add(obj);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg)
            {

                app.setPodcastArray(array);

                if(setToArray) {
                    podcastListArrayAdapter = new PodcastListArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_podcast_list_item, array);
                    Listv.setAdapter(podcastListArrayAdapter);
                    app.setCurrentPodcast(array.get(0));
                }
                else
                {
                    app.setCurrentPodcast(array.get(0));
                    home_title.setText(app.getCurrentPodcast().getTitle());
                }

                try {
                    if (swipeContainer.isRefreshing()) {
                        swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }catch (NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found an error.
Look into *onCreateView*. You have if/else there, and **only in the first branch home_title is being initialised**, not in the second one.

So you have Activity -> ViewPager -> (Page1 - PlaceHolder fragment with home_title initialized) && (Page2 - PlaceHolder fragment without home_title initialized)

You call

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
```

from the **second** page(fragment). But it knows nothing about home_title! I.e. you're calling not the home_title from the first page, but home_title from the second page (which, again, is not initialized!).

There're multiple possible ways of fixing it.
The simplest for you would be to

1. Make home_title public (or introduce a getter for it)
2. Then call it this way:

   ```
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0).home_title.setText(app.getCurrentPodcast().getTitle());
   ```

I.e. explicitly call home_title from the first page.

In this case it'd be over engineering, but you can also think about [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) as a way to organize cross-fragment collaboration. It'd make it bit cleaner (imho)
And my last 5 cents - you'll make your own life simpler, if you keep different fragments in separate classes. This logic in onCreateView is hardly maintainable.